# How do you create a debug breakpoint in compiled code

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to create a complier on which Complile my code wriiten in c#.net. I am working on debugger  i have create complier but is there is a way through which i can put a break point on my code file and when click on the Run button it will be stop where i put break point Please tell me if any body knows the code how we put the break point on the program c# files

Comment: Spaces are allowed in question titles.

Answer (score 3):

Break points aren't part of the compiled binary - although you could inject calls to [`Debugger.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) into your code.

You may want to look at the [debugger API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384366%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).